# Comparing the values of a cell in a workbook to a cell in a closed workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007, match, vba

I have a list of values in Workbook A that I need to find in Workbook B, which is closed.

Pseudocode of what I am trying to achieve:

```
For each entry x in Workbook A
     Search through the column in Workbook B for entry x
     Copy that value from Workbook B along with the value cell next to it
Next entry
```

I've tried to store the values of the cells as variables, but I'm not sure how to increment the cell value so that I can continue to move down the list.

I've tried using the Match function, but I'm not sure how to properly compare the values.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try using Vlookup:

```
Sub example()
Dim ans As Variant
Dim WB_B As Workbook
Dim TWB As Workbook ' your workbook A
Dim WB_B_rng As Range
Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
Set WB_B = Workbooks.Open("your workbook B's full path")
Set WB_B_rng = WB_B.Sheets("workbookB's sheetname").Range("data table's range")

TWB.Activate
Sheets("workbookA's sheetname").Range("A1").Select ' or where your record's start located
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

ans = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Value, WB_B_rng, 2, 0)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ans
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate 'goes down to the next cell until it's empty
Loop

WB_B.close
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for, however, when I run the code from Excel, the following error is thrown: 

`Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class`

Comment: Try using Application.VLookup instead:
    ans = Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Value, WB_B_rng, 2, 0)

Comment: That fixed the issue. The code runs now, however, all of the reference in column B (ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = ans) are invalid references ("#REF!"). I'm not sure how to fix that. The Workbook B that I'm using as values in column B, which is the one I'm referencing in WB_B_range.

Comment: Assuming your matching values are at column A and the lookup values are in column B in your workbookB, check if the WB_B_rng includes both column A and B. E.g. Set WB_B_rng = WB_B.Sheets("Sheet1").range($A1:$B100")

Comment: I figured it out. I wasn't understanding out VLookUp worked. I was limiting my range to narrowly, and then trying to return a value that was outside of the range. Thanks again for your help!